# AngularJS - ui-router: Using Resolve to Autoload Record for Edit

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn ui-router's resolve ...

I have app.js where the routes are defined and editApp.js, my main controller for all the edit screens.

I am trying to "autoload" the proper record from an API for all of the EDIT subviews so I have a resolve on my /edit/:id route.

This is editApp.js

```
(function(){
        var EditAppController = function($scope, $state, $http, $location, $window, _){

        }; // end EditAppController

        EditAppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$http', '$location', '$window', '_'];

        angular.module('ARM').controller('EditAppController', EditAppController);
    }());
```

This is app.js:

```
var ARM = angular.module('ARM', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

ARM.constant('_', window._)
    .run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope._ = window._;
    });

ARM.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/landing.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })

        .state('prefs', {
            url: '/prefs',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/prefs.html'
        })

        //EDITS HERE
        .state('edit', {
            url: '/edit/:id',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/editapp.html',
            controller: 'EditAppController',
            resolve:{
                loan: function($http, $stateParams){
                    return $http.get('/api/loans/'+$stateParams.id)
                }
            }
        })

        .state('edit.farmer', {
            url: '/farmer',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/farmer.html'
        })

        .state('edit.applicant', {
            url: '/applicant',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/applicant.html'
        })

        .state('edit.partner', {
            url: '/partner',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/partner.html'
        })

        .state('edit.quests', {
            url: '/quests',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/quests.html'
        })

        .state('edit.states', {
            url: '/states',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/states.html'
        })

        .state('edit.farms', {
            url: '/farms',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/farms.html'
        })

        .state('edit.crops', {
            url: '/crops',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/crops.html'
        })

        .state('edit.insurance', {
            url: '/insurance',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/edit/insurance.html'
        })

        // NEW HERE
        .state('new', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/new',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/newApp.html',
            controller: 'NewAppController'
        })

        .state('new.farmer', {
            url: '/farmer',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/farmer.html'
        })

        .state('new.applicant', {
            url: '/applicant',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/applicant.html'
        })

        .state('new.partner', {
            url: '/partner',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/partner.html'
        })

        .state('new.quest', {
            url: '/quest',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/quest.html'
        })

        .state('new.states', {
            url: '/states',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/states.html'
        })

        .state('new.counties', {
            url: '/counties',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/counties.html'
        })

        .state('new.farms', {
            url: '/farms',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/farms.html'
        })

        .state('new.crops', {
            url: '/crops',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/crops.html'
        })

        .state('new.insurance', {
            url: '/insurance',
            templateUrl: '/ang/views/new/insurance.html'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

I've read the documentation and I just don't understand how to get the $scope variable into the controller. Could someone help me get that value (loan) into my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `loan` as it is another injectable dependency

```
(function(){
    var EditAppController = function($scope, $state, $http, $location, $window, _, loan){
    }; // end EditAppController

    EditAppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$http', '$location', '$window', '_', 'loan'];

    angular.module('ARM').controller('EditAppController', EditAppController);
}());
```

Comment: That's what I thought the documentation indicated and that seems so easy but when I do that, the whole "app" breaks ... http://cl.ly/XL2e

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loanProvider <- loan
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=loanProvider%20%3C-%20loan
    at http://www.armlend.local/scripts/angular.js:78:12
    at http://www.armlend.local/scripts/angular.js:3705:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://www.armlend.local/scripts/angular.js:3832:39)
    at http://www.armlend.local/scripts/angular.js:3710:45
    at getService (http://www.armlend.local/scripts/angular.js:3832:39)
    at invoke (http://www.armlend.local/scripts/angular.js:3859:13)

Comment: I created jsfiddle with resolve and it works :  http://jsfiddle.net/michal_taborowski/tdLp1zu0/. Maybe you have a typo somewhere.